Find the value of $P=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{10} n\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{1+n}+\dfrac{2^2}{2+n}+\dfrac{3^2}{3+n}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{10+n}\right\}}$
Find the value of $P=\displaystyle{\sum_n^{10} n\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{1+n}+\dfrac{2^2}{2+n}+\dfrac{3^2}{3+n}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{10+n}\right\}} $
Given answer is $(55)^2\over2$
By writing the terms and observation I get that this series $P$ is equivalent to $$\sum^{20}_{k=1}\sum^k_{r=1}\dfrac{r^2(k-r)}{k}=\sum^{20}_{k=1}\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}-\dfrac{k(k+1)^2}{4}=\sum^{20}_{k=1}\dfrac{k(k+1)(k-1)}{12}={20\times21\times(209)\over12\times2}$$
$$\boxed{\begin{aligned}  \sum_n^{10} n\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{1+n}+\dfrac{2^2}{2+n}+\dfrac{3^2}{3+n}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{10+n}\right\} &=1\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{2}+\dfrac{2^2}{3}+\dfrac{3^2}{6}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{11}\right\}\\
&+2\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{3}+\dfrac{2^2}{4}+\dfrac{3^2}{5}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{12}\right\}\\
&+3\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{6}+\dfrac{2^2}{7}+\dfrac{3^2}{8}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{13}\right\}\\
&+\dots\\
&+10\left\{\dfrac{1^2}{11}+\dfrac{2^2}{12}+\dfrac{3^2}{13}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{20}\right\}
\end{aligned}}$$ here I combineterms with same denominators and get that double sum.
but ultimately answer does not match. What am I doing wrong?

Maybe write down how you got the first double sum. This double sum is already not $\frac{(55)^2}{2}$.

@garondal $$\boxed{\begin{aligned}  \sum_n^{10} n\left{\dfrac{1^2}{1+n}+\dfrac{2^2}{2+n}+\dfrac{3^2}{3+n}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{10+n}\right} &=1\left{\dfrac{1^2}{2}+\dfrac{2^2}{3}+\dfrac{3^2}{4}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{11}\right}\
&+2\left{\dfrac{1^2}{3}+\dfrac{2^2}{4}+\dfrac{3^2}{5}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{12}\right}\
&+3\left{\dfrac{1^2}{4}+\dfrac{2^2}{5}+\dfrac{3^2}{6}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{13}\right}\
&+\dots\
&+10\left{\dfrac{1^2}{11}+\dfrac{2^2}{12}+\dfrac{3^2}{13}+\dots+\dfrac{10^2}{20}\right}
\end{aligned}}$$ here I combineterms with same denominators and get that double sum.

The originally sum has 100 terms and your double sum has 210 terms, so it's not correct.

Your double sum is wrong because you have final sums in the problem. This method would be good for infinite sums, but not for finite. For example in the original sum there is only $1$ summand with the denominator $20$. In your double sum there are $20$ summands with that denominator. You have many redundant summands for large denominators.

@Aig Yes obviously get it. But couldn't find it before. Thanks.

Use Approach0 for searching. It recognizes TEX, and all of MathSE and AoPS are indexed.
